# Laptop display "unknown" and can't detect external displays

Tags: 11.10, display

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Samsung laptop.

On unity, I can't even know what graphics I have (in system settings). However, after I switched to gnome, I know can see my graphics: GeForce GT 330M/PCI/SSE2.

But my main issue remains: If I go under system settings -> displays, my display is listed as "unknown" and I can't detect my external display. During the ubuntu installation, my external screen worked (it was a clone of my laptops screen).

I tried to update my driver in system settings -> additional driver (yes, I then rebooted), I tried to update it manually within the console (`sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`), but still nothing.

EDIT: On another topic I've seen someone asking to run a `ddcprobe` to retrieve more info. Here is what I get:

```
mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
VESA BIOS Extensions not detected.
```

Comment: Alright got it working somehow... For those with the same problem, that's how I solved it: Open console (ctrl alt t) type in nvidia-settings
A window will pop up, and just play around there till it works... Was pretty hard for me with only half of my pixels working, had to permanently move the window around to be able to read all the stuff but I got it down.

Good luck ;-)

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer so you can mark it answered?

Answer (score 1):

This problem was solved by the OP:

> For those with the same problem, that's how I solved it: Open console
>   (ctrl alt t) type in nvidia-settings A window will pop up, and just
>   play around there till it works... Was pretty hard for me with only
>   half of my pixels working, had to permanently move the window around
>   to be able to read all the stuff but I got it down.